# Airflow start date not running as planned

Tags: python, airflow

I am a newbie here. I would like to schedule airflow to run delta on everyday same hours like 18:50hour without backfill the data.

This is what I set on the DAGS. But it keeps backfilling and downloads the data from 5th Nov 2018 to date. How can I change it to download delta only?

```
WORKFLOW_START_DATE = datetime(2018, 11, 5), 
WORKFLOW_SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = "50 18 * * *"

WORKFLOW_DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'admin',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': WORKFLOW_START_DATE,
    'email': ['airflow@testing.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='download',
    bash_command='-c "test_download.sh {{ execution_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y") }}"',
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `catchup_by_default=False` in the `airflow.cfg` file or apply `catchup=False` to your dag.

Example is as below:

```py
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 12, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'schedule_interval': '@hourly',
}

dag = DAG('tutorial', catchup=False, default_args=default_args)
```

**Documentation Link**: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup

Comment: Thanks so much.. Will try it out